# How can I use Apache conf include files?

Tags: apache

When I put the following into my Apache.conf file my site works:

```
<Directory /home/demo/popHealth/public>
   RailsEnv development
   AllowOverride all
   Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

However it will get lost during instances where the configuration file gets rebuilt. I see the following comment in the file:

```
# To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
# Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/demo/demo.concinnity.me/*.conf"
```

I put this text verbatim into a file in that location, but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried uncommenting the include line so that there was no explicit directive to include those files, and that didn't work either. How can I use include files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to uncomment and adjust the line:

   `# Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/demo/demo.concinnity.me/MyInclude.conf"`
   (Make sure to specify the correct path here).
2. You can open this file and modify it:

   `"/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/demo/demo.concinnity.me/MyInclude.conf"`.

Comment: These instructions are wrong. You should not modify the `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` file directly because changes you may will be erased when apache is updated.